# How to upload/download file to a user's OneDrive using Microsoft Graph in MAUI

Tags: azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a new MAUI application (Android, iOS, MacCatalyst, and Windows) that I need to upload/download a SQLite file to the user's OneDrive account "App Folder" location for my application. In another Xamarin.Forms application (Android, iOS, UWP), I used the Microsoft MSAL library to authenticate the user, get the user account and then the Token. After user authentication I used the Microsoft Graph Client to perform the upload/download of the file.

But the process used in the Xamarin.Forms application does not work for my MAUI application.
The MSAL library is not compatible with a MAUI application. And I since I can not authenticate, I am not sure if the Microsoft Graph Client  is compatible or not.

So can someone help me with how you can perform this upload/download process in a MAUI application for all the platforms, please? A sample of this process would be great.

Orgbrat